# Check a sheet for new items in cell and add new items in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 spreadsheets; 1 for raw data (Sheet 1), and 1 for computation and data transformation (Sheet 2)

As the number of items in Sheet 1 increases day on day, is there a code that can check Sheet 1 against Sheet 2 for new items, and then add the new items in the first empty row in Sheet 2

For example in Sheet 1 I have:

Apple
Orange
Mango
Pear
Grapes

but in Sheet 2, I have:

Apple
Orange
Mango

How do I check Sheet 2 for new items in Sheet 1 (i.e. Pear & Grapes), and then add them into the next empty row (i.e. row directly below Mango)

Thanks in Advance!

**Edit: 04/11/18**

Thank you for your help! The provided solution works as intended. Now I have a case b where I need to add new items into the next empty row for a "Sheet 3" from "Sheet 1" based on a set of criteria

For example from a centralised raw data Sheet 1:

[image]

I want to transfer new entries that are Fruits, Red, & Round to Sheet 3 (i.e. in this case Tomato is not in Sheet 3, and I want it over):

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: All new or just unique new? Also, please share your best attempt at solving this. See [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hard Coded

Assuming the data is in column "B" and starts in the second row (or Cell "B2") in **both** worksheets:

```
Sub CopyData()
  Const cLngFirstRow As Long = 2
  Const cIntCol As String = "B"

  Dim oRng1 As Range
  Dim oRng2 As Range
  Dim Cell1 As Range
  Dim Cell2 As Range

  Dim lngRow As Long 'Row to write to
  Dim blnNotFound As Boolean

  With Sheet1
    Set oRng1 = .Range(.Cells(cLngFirstRow, cIntCol), _
        .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, cIntCol).End(xlUp).Row, cIntCol))
  End With
  With Sheet2
    Set oRng2 = .Range(.Cells(cLngFirstRow, cIntCol), _
        .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, cIntCol).End(xlUp).Row, cIntCol))
    lngRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cIntCol).End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  For Each Cell1 In oRng1
    For Each Cell2 In oRng2
      If Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value Then
        blnNotFound = False
        Exit For
      End If
      blnNotFound = True
    Next
    If blnNotFound Then
      lngRow = lngRow + 1
      Sheet2.Cells(lngRow, cIntCol) = Cell1.Value
      blnNotFound = False
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Note: The Sheet1 and Sheet2 are **CodeNames**. You can rename the worksheet names as you wish.

Comment: You don't need If blnNotFound = True .... simply If blnNotFound . It is already a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim I as long 
I = 1
Do until isempty(worksheets.cells(1,i).value)
```

Compare the rows if the cell in the one worksheet is empty you have to copy it.

```
I = I + 1
Loop
```

At the beginning you need to set I on 1 Else you would start at 0 which wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `RemoveDuplicates()` method of `Range` object:

```
Sub CheckSheet()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(Array(1))
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```